# Story with a supercomputer with a God complex

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, computers

I can't remember the title or author in which a new super computer is built and it answers the question...

> **Is there a god?**

(omninously) with

> **There is now.**

Comment: I've removed the subjective "which is best" bit, leaving only the story-ident question.

Answer (score 23):

The story you are thinking of is *[Answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20160411155540/http://www.alteich.com/oldsite/answer.htm)* (1954) by [Fredric Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredric_Brown), the master of the short-short. The part in question:

> "Thank you," said Dwar Reyn. "It shall be a question that no single
>  cybernetics machine has been able to answer."
>
>  He turned to face the machine. "Is there a God?"
>
>  The mighty voice answered without hesitation, without the clicking of
>  single relay.
>
>  "Yes, now there is a God."

Comment: You are correct sir, and can have my +1

Answer (score 7):

I think that would have to be the computer in Isaac Asimov's The Last Question, who, upon being asked The Last Question

> Creates the universe.

Strictly speaking, that is a short-story and not a novel, though.

Comment: Note to all for context: This was written when the question was asking for the most powerful computer in a book or movie, and so was correct in those versions.